# Jquery Autocomplete Plugin works only Once in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I want to search the city from my database. when user type some initials. For this I used the following autocomplete jquery plugin, (ASP.Net 3.5 + VS 2008)

```
<link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Search_CS.ashx");
});    
</script>
```

and my Search_CS.ashx class is,

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search_CS" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text; 

public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection con = DataSetClass.conDB())
    {
        //con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
        //        .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT cname from City where cname LIKE        @CityText + '%'", con))
        {
            //cmd.CommandText = "select ContactName from Customers where " +
            //"ContactName like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["cname"])
                        .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            con.Close();
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This works fine but the problem is plugin works only once. after that when i type initials, autocomplete does not work untill i refresh the page. I tried many solutions but all in vain. Please help me out as i am stucking here from 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Thing that need to remember that $(Document).ready() calls only first time when page load. After then for all ajax/partial postback it method will not call means your text box no longer will have that auto-complete functionality. So get off this problem you should wrap you code in some function like

```
function Bind()
{
$("#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Search_CS.ashx");
}
```

and then call it in

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    Bind();
}
```

and in

```
function pageLoad()
{
Bind();
}
```

have a look to this great article http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: Thanks! I have solved my problem and now I understand the logic. Now there is a little problem, I am using Firefox browser. when i type the initials in the textbox then autocomplete works fine and show the chhoices list. If i press enter key to choose one of them, then my grid show the correct match, but if i click on the item from autocomplete list, then it matches the initials that i have typed in textbox and i got more matches in grid then the exact item on that i clicked. what should i do???

Comment: I am not sure but it seems you are listening to wrong event(~KeyDown or ~FocusOut) in either case. I dont have answer but can say subscribe to latest event to bind your grid.